# Calculate simple math expression pass as a command line argument

Tags: haskell

I'm a newbie in Haskell and I'm lost. I was trying to parse a math expression, but really don't know how Haskell programming works well. So what I'm trying to write is a program to resolve a simple math expression. I'm looking for ideas on how I could resolve by giving arguments.

The command line could look like : `./math "3 + 2"` or `./math "5 * 8"`

My code looks like this:

```hs
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Text.Printf

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    printf "%.2f" args[1] + args[2]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haskell has no `array[index]` syntax. It does have `list!!index` syntax (which isn't really special syntax at all, [`!!`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) is just an infix-function defined in the prelude). Note that Haskell indices are 0-based and unlike in Bash, the zeroth argument is not the command name itself, so you probably want indices `0` and `1`.

Also, in Haskell function application binds more tightly than any operators. So, if you were to write

```
    printf "%.2f" args!!0 + args!!1
```

it would parse as `((printf "%.2f" args)!!0) + (args!!1)`, which is obviously not right. You need to make explicit what precedence you want:

```
    printf "%.2f" (args!!0 + args!!1)
```

or as we like to do it, with `$` instead of parens:

```
    printf "%.2f" $ args!!0 + args!!1
```

That's still not right, because the arguments come in as *strings*, but the addition should be performed on numbers. For this, you need to *read* the numbers; I'd suggest you do that separately:

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let a, b :: Double
        Just a = readMaybe $ args!!0
        Just b = readMaybe $ args!!1
    printf "%.2f" $ a + b
```

```
$ runhaskell Argsmath.hs 3 2
5.00
```

Of course this will *not* allow you to do stuff like `./math "5 * 8"` because you have no means of parsing the `*`. For that, something `read`-based would be awkward; I suggest you check out parser combinator libraries, there are plenty of tutorials around; [this one](http://akashagrawal.me/beginners-guide-to-megaparsec/) seems to be nice and simple.

Comment: Thanks for the information! But I have a minor error and I don't why I have this error `printf: bad formatting char 'f'`

Comment: Yeah, I selected the wrong type to read: you want floats, not integers. Fixed.